# Spring Data Elastic Search vs Java High Level REST Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I'm new to Elastic search. We are building a Spring boot application with Elastic search.

For integrating my Spring boot application either we can use `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` or `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`.

**Can anyone please elaborate on which option would be overall better and why?**

Comment: Others stumbling into this question may ask 'What about *Jest*'?  Well, the [Jest project](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) unfortunately is no longer being actively developed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` internally can use the `transport(soon to be deprecated in ES 8.X)` or `rest-high-level-client` Please refer [elasticsearch client section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients) for more information and how to configure them.

And from the same link :

> Spring data Elasticsearch operates upon an Elasticsearch client that
>   is connected to a single Elasticsearch node or a cluster. Although the
>   Elasticsearch Client can be used to work with the cluster,
>   applications using Spring Data Elasticsearch normally use the higher
>   level abstractions of Elasticsearch Operations and Elasticsearch
>   Repositories.

Bottom line is that you can directly use `rest-high-level` client in your spring boot application but if you want more abstraction then you can use the `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` dependency and use its method which provides more abstraction although internally it would use the client offered by Elasticsearch.

Comment: which one would be better if i consider points like performance, future upgrade of ES version etc...?

Comment: @DevChauhan IMHO you should directly use the rest-high level java client so that you don't have to wait till spring data release the integration with new versions, also performance shouldn't be the issue but still having an abstraction might make it difficult and add obliviously some overhead although don't think it would be too much

Comment: @DevChauhan hope I answered your question, let me know if you need more info

Comment: @DevChauhan sure, just one question based on this question is that now you will not have spring data dependency correct as I explained its better to use the rest-high level client directly which I hv been using in my projects and never faced many issues while upgrading, also please keep in mind that elasticsearch is evolving very fast and ES 8 will have again quite some breaking changes, it will remove the support of `type` permanently, so it would be great if you can provide your use cases also in the question  otherwise I;ll give general ans inst of specific while ans, hope you got my point.